# Unique id´s/Slugs for wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that have profile pages with buddy press, and it forces me to use  clean permalinks, where the url and slug are the same. Something like this: members/profile/name

I can change the body tag to output the last part of the url in the body tag to style it with css. However, there is several pages with url´s like this: members/profile/name/notifications which makes it hard to style theses pages individual.

Is there any way to extract a unique id/class for the pages regardless the permalink structure?

Comment: That's not clear at all. Provide more info/code.

Comment: Did you have any success with this... I guessing you want to be able to give your pages more meaningful id attributes for CSS namespacing, rather than page_12, you might want about_us